# Blender Game Engine Rendering Problem

Tags: rendering, game-engine

I am working on a game and this happened.
I have a Cube with an array modifier.
When i view my level in the viewport it looks ok but when i press "p" it looks like the Normals are inverted(which is not the case).

Does someone know what the problem could be?

Left: Viewport ____  Right: Blender Game Engine Render

[image: Left: Viewport Right: Blender Game Engine Render]

Answer (score 1):

Never mind
I found the solution
You just have to set the Alpha Blend to Alpha Clip in the Material Options.

Comment: Do you even use alpha?